# Not understanding Observable.from and Observable.just in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am new to Rxjava. I am following a video tutorial where there is a code example that calls an API and gets string result using flatmap. Below is the code:

```
twitchAPI.getTopGamesObservable()
                .flatMap(new Func1<Twitch, Observable<Top>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Top> call(Twitch twitch) {
                Observable<Top> rtnTop =  Observable.from(twitch.getTop());
                Log.d("LogRx", "Size for FROM:"  + "\n");

                return rtnTop;
            }
        })
                .flatMap(new Func1<Top, Observable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<String> call(Top top) {
                Log.d("LogRx", "Size for JUST:"  + "\n");
                return Observable.just(top.getGame().getName());
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {     }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {    }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {  Log.d("LogRx", s);      }

        });
```

But i am not really understanding the sequence of how this code works.

And the confusion is because of observable.from() & observable.just(). I know that observable.from() will give N emissions for a list and observable.just() will give 1 emissions(a list).

So, does it mean that the second flatMap is called N times because Observable.from() inside  the first flatMap is emitting each item in the list each time. And for the second flatMap the onNext() of subscriber is called N times too(once for each call of 2nd flatmap)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, does it mean that the second flatMap is called N times because Observable.from() inside the first flatMap is emitting each item in the list each time.

The second flat map (`.flatMap(new Func1<Top, Observable<String>>() {`) is called `twitch.getTop().size()` times.

> And for the second flatMap the onNext() of subscriber is called N times too

This is true. You get one observable, each with one value, per `Top`. The number of values delivered to `onNext` is equal to the number of `Top`s.

Which makes the second flat map kinda bloated. You might as well `map` a `Top` to `String`.

---

Unrelated: You may want to find a more recent tutorial. RxJava1 died almost a year ago.

> RxJava 1.x is now officially **end-of-life (EOL)**. No further developments, bugfixes, enhancements, javadoc changes or maintenance will be provided by this project after version **1.3.8** and after [31 Mar 2018].
>
> Users are encouraged to [migrate to 2.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0). In accordance, the wiki will be updated in the coming months to describe 2.x features and properties.

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.3.8

Comment: Thanks for the advice of RxJava2. But still a bit confusion with the answer. The second flat map (`.flatMap(new Func1<Top, Observable<String>>() {`) is called `twitch.getTop().size()` times. So, what I am understanding is that - `first flatMap` is emitting one by one items and  `twitch.getTop().size()` times. Then shouldn't it be executing the code for Log `Log.d("LogRx", "Size for FROM:"  + "\n");` inside the 1st `flatMap` everytime too? If not then how does it store and loop through each item in second `flatMap`?

Comment: The first flat map is executed once. It takes one `Twitch` and makes N `Observable<Top>` of it. The second flat map is executed N times - once of each `Top`. The second flat map takes one `Top` and makes one `Observable<String>` of it. Now you have N times `Observable<String>` each will emit one `String`. In the end `onNext` will run N times - once for each `String`. This is the worst example to illustrate `flatMap`. Flat map is executed once per each item, not once per each observable. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html Again, the second flat map should be `map` instead.